# 3d vibration data with Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I'm trying to use FFT method in python to convert 3d vibration data collected from accelerometer. We set the frequency to 50 hz.

When I was trying to plot the data, I got a weird graph. Can someone please tell me why?

```
import scipy.fftpack
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Y = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/0000/Documents/0000/data/accelData1.xls')


y1 = Y['X'].values
y2 = Y['Y'].values
y3 = Y['Z'].values

y = y1 + y2 +y3

N = 1280
T = 0.01
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)

yf = np.abs(scipy.fft(y))
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)


plt.plot(yf[0:N//2], xf, label = 'signal')
```

fft plot

[image]

Comment: refer [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for Matplotlib plot (it should be x,y). Also you have vary high value at the beginning of `yf` list , so check for values from `yf[0]` to `yf[1]`. Also please explain whats weird in the graph

Comment: Adding the three components does make sense if you want to watch a vector at 45 degrees to x and y. Absolute value would be to add the squares and take the root. What is also unclear is why you have a DC offset in accelerometer data. Are you in a constantly accelerating reference frame?

Answer (score 0):

Your graph is upside down, you inverted x and y when plotting